# MySQL - Alternatives to "text" columns to store HTML Content

Tags: mysql, text, nosql

I have a large PHP application and a MySQL Database for my company. All communications such as emails, quotes which are HTML based, are surrently stored in "text" columns in MySql tables. These tables have grown to be quite large now, 15-16GB in size, and are slow to restore, move to other servers etc.

Is there a more modern approach to storing information of this nature, perhaps a different kind of database altogether which is perfect for storing documents. Obviously this data would need to be retrievable from the core application etc.

I've heard of things such as MongoDB but don't know if these are designed to cater for this kind of storage.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to move away from "Text" columns? I'm sure this must be an old fashioned technique by now.

Regards

James

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that your question is "What options exist for storing data because I think TEXT columns in relational databases are old-fashioned?".

Regarding the question...there's lots of different tools and substrates for storing data - apart from processing, that's what computers **do**. As to which is the most appropriate, well that depends on how you want to access the data, update it and dispose of it: how robust these mechanisms need to be : how fast they need to operate.

> don't know if these are designed to cater for this kind of storage.

But the only thing you've told us about the storage is that there is a lot of it. You should certainly acquaint yourself with the CAP theorem. It looks deceptively simple. But you're going to get into a lot of problems mixing different databases in the same application if you don't know *exactly* what you're doing.

> and are slow to restore, move to other servers etc.

I don't know what you mean by "etc". But if your problem is the size of the data, then the solution is to simply partition the dataset - and its probably more practical to do this in tables with a unified view than to use MySQL's table partitioning.

Depending on the size of the data, you might also consider compressing the HTML data before inserting it - after all, you can't index it.

Yes, you could rewrite your application to run on a NoSQL database - if you exclusively use trivial ORM that should be straightforward. But it doesn't reduce the volume of data.